# Disable bullet rails for one test file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bullet

I have followed this suggestion and I have disabled bullet for one test file.
https://tosbourn.com/ignore-bullet-rspec/
But I am now getting an error from bullet

```
Failure/Error:
expect { perform_notifications }.to raise_error(
Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError,
/AVOID eager loading detected/)
```